# Question about non-degenerate polynomials, and a proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was watching a video lecture on *Algebraic Geometry*, but I do not have their book. Something came up that confused me.

What is a non-degenerate homogeneous quadratic polynomial?  Please with few examples of degenerate polynomials and why they fail.

The reason I am asking this is because apparently any non-degenerate homogeneous quadratic polynomial in projective space can be written as $f(x,y,z)=xz-y^2$ via a transformation. Does someone know how to prove this claim?

EDIT, Will Jagy: the result is Theorem I.9 on page 15 of [PLESKEN](https://books.google.com/books?id=4TAxOSzxODUC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Let%20g%20be%20an%20integral%20ternary%20quadratic%20form,%20which%20is%20indefinite%20and%20nondegenerate&source=bl&ots=ETCH01cGlX&sig=kx0OSGeCR185rDg_f0N4DWG_ewU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYlMTgn_XJAhUWwWMKHTjqDXUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Let%20g%20be%20an%20integral%20ternary%20quadratic%20form%2C%20which%20is%20indefinite%20and%20nondegenerate&f=false)

Comment: Is this video freely available? If so, it may help to provide a link.

Comment: Any homogeneous quadratic polynomial in $n$ variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ over $\mathbb C$ can be brought into the form $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_r^2$ for some $0 \leq r \leq n$ after a change of variables. The form is degenerate if $r < n$. Maybe it helps to think of this as the rank of a representing matrix, if you know something about that correspondence.

Comment: It cannot be all polynomials, because $zx - y^2$ is isotropic over $\mathbb Q$ and therefore $\mathbb Z.$ This is one pages 507-508 of Fricke and Klein for isotropic (indefinite) ternaries https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false  I can explain more but need more detail

Comment: This is briefly alluded to in Magnus, Noneuclidean Tesselations and Their Groups, but explicit in an article, W. Plesken https://books.google.com/books?id=4TAxOSzxODUC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Let+g+be+an+integral+ternary+quadratic+form,+which+is+indefinite+and+nondegenerate&source=bl&ots=ETCH01cGlX&sig=kx0OSGeCR185rDg_f0N4DWG_ewU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYlMTgn_XJAhUWwWMKHTjqDXUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Let%20g%20be%20an%20integral%20ternary%20quadratic%20form%2C%20which%20is%20indefinite%20and%20nondegenerate&f=false

Comment: Yes exactly the proof from W. Plesken, I have hard time understanding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example. We begin with an isotropic ternary quadratic form,
$$ f(x,y,z) = 24 x^2 + 24 y^2 + 24 z^2 -43 yz - 43 z x - 43 x y.  $$
Its Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is

$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
48 &  -43 & -43 \\
-43 & 48 & -43 \\
-43 &  -43 & 48
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Isotropic means that there is at least one triple $(x,y,z)$ of integers, not all equal to zero, with $f(x,y,z) = 0.$ Nondegenerate means $\det H \neq 0.$

The theorem in question guarantees an integer matrix,

$$
R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
58 & 61 & 18 \\
18 & -25 & 15 \\
15 & 55 & 58
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Back to that in a minute. The indicated form, $y^2 - z x,$ has Hessian matrix
$$
G = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 &  0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 &  0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Alright, the relationship is $R^T H R = 157339 G.$ That is,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
58 & 18 & 15 \\
61 & -25 & 55 \\
18 & 15 & 58
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
48 &  -43 & -43 \\
-43 & 48 & -43 \\
-43 &  -43 & 48
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
58 & 61 & 18 \\
18 & -25 & 15 \\
15 & 55 & 58
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 &  0 & -157339 \\
0 & 314678 & 0 \\
-157339 &  0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The rows of $R$ tell us that, for any integers $(u,v),$ we always have
$$ f( 58 u^2 + 61 uv + 18 v^2, 18 u^2 -25 uv + 15 v^2, 15 u^2 + 55 uv + 58 v^2 ) = 0 $$